# Is possible to put html form in svg image?

Tags: html, css, forms, svg, input

I didn't found answer nowhere on the internet.

I have some not much easy contact form to code because of its design. The yellow parts should be prepared to fill. Because of its design I thought the best way will be to make svg and put some html (like `<input>`) into it. But it looks its not that easy as I thought. [I'm adding preview here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wflWs.png)

I tried `<foreignobject>` tag but it doesn't work, maybe I exported svg wrong way. Nothing was shown, I could see the code in element inspector but it didn't highlight anywhere on site.

Is it possible to make it with just html and svg code, or I need some js? Or I'm just inventing something stupid and the pixel perfect code should make better job for me.

Sorry for that silly question but I am really wondering if its even possible, thank you all.

Comment: Is this on Firefox, Chrome, something else? Also it's foreignObject (capital O) as SVG is case sensitive.

Comment: I see. Its form for website so I need to work it in all broswers. But it didn't make any change.

Comment: Add your markup to the question in the form of a [mcve]

Comment: _“Or I'm just inventing something stupid and the pixel perfect code should make better job for me”_ – the stupidity would rather be in expecting “pixel perfection” in the first place. // Pretty sure an acceptable version of this could be done with HTML & CSS, without SVG. (Meaning SVG not as the main means, but optional as background image(s) to achieve parts of the postcard look not excluded of course.)